# get table data base on pivot table in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have M:N relationship between tables handymen and categories. So, pivot table is category_handyman. How to fetch all handymen data, who have category_id=1 in pivot table? I wanted to do something like this: (but this doesnt work)

```
        $handymen = Handyman::with('categories')
                ->where('category_id', 1)
                ->get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **whereHas()** method to filter on related records:

```
$handymen = Handyman::whereHas('categories', function($query) {
  $query->whereId(1);
})->get();
```